# Moderator site analytics are wrong for Meta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, site-stats

On the *meta* site for Biology (and according to comments **all** metas), the moderator statistics page has a 'default' date jump-to for private beta start:

[image: Meta Site Analytics date jumper]

Things are fine on the *main* site:

[image: Main Site Analytics date jumper]

Furthermore, whilst I can't go into detail here, the site statistics for meta visits are wrongly recorded—I'll post in the Teacher's Lounge with [specifics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/conversation/moderator-site-analytics-wrong-for-meta-sites-specifics).

Comment: Same on Meta Programmers.

Comment: On Linguistics it's fine. Same for Chinese Language & Usage.

Comment: @Alenanno: The main sites look like they're fine everywhere, it's jut the *meta* sites that are affected. Are you sure that Meta.Linguistics, etc. are fine?

Comment: @TheEstablishment My bad. You're right, on Meta they look like the screenshot examples.

Comment: It happens on Drupal Answers too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should be pulling from the parent site here since that's the database in which these events are logged.

Starting with the next build the dates should be correct (or hidden in the case where no private beta occurred, for the first few sites).

Comment: Will that fix the inaccuracies too? :)

Comment: @Rory - Nope! We've grown past the point that Google started changing the number to sampling...nothing we can do about that without a very large monetary investment :-/